# Why is 'image' not a member of 'UIImageView' or 'UIImage'?

Tags: swift, uiimage

I try to access an image from an UIImageView which has a unique tag in my storyboard (211). The image should be nil if it is empty. My code so far:

```
if self.view.viewWithTag(211).image != nil{
            print("EXISTS!")
        }
```

This works (prints exists):

```
if self.view.viewWithTag(211) != nil{
          print("EXISTS!")
}
```

I thought that viewWithTag() searches *all* views (all subviews and the view itself) for the tag. The tag is found, but Xcode (8) gives me following error: *"Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'image'"*. But I also thought that UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, isn't it? So viewWithTag() should work.
I tried to change my code a bit like this:

```
if self.view.viewWithTag(211) as! UIImageView.image? != nil{
                print("EXISTS!")
            }
```

But it showed me this: 

*"var 'image' is not a member type of 'UIImageView'."*

I am a beginner in Xcode and Swift, so I would really appreciate your help!

If you have any further questions, please write a comment below.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: A recommendation - don't use tags. Create an `@IBOutlet`  for your `imageView` instead and access it directly.

Comment: @Sulthan Hello, thanks for the recommendation! My current problem is that I have 42 ImageViews which I would like to pack into a two-dimensional array, but this did not really work. I've heard of Outlet Collections, but they're only one-dimensional arrays. So I try to handle it with tags instead of 42 Outlets, but another idea would be great ;-)

Comment: Thats probably a task for collection view.

Comment: Ok, I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: I now solved it by using 'subviews'. Pretty cool thing btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.image` property can be used on an *instance* of the `UIImageView`
class, not on the class itself. So this would compile:

```
if (self.view.viewWithTag(211) as! UIImageView).image != nil {
    print("EXISTS!")
}
```

but it will crash at runtime if no view with tag 211 exists, or
if that view is not an instance of 
`UImageView` (or some subclass). A safe version is to use optional casting with `as?`:

```
if (self.view.viewWithTag(211) as? UIImageView)?.image != nil {
    print("EXISTS!")
}
```

If you combine that with optional binding then you get the unwrapped
`UIImage` in the "success" case as well:

```
if let imageView = self.view.viewWithTag(211) as? UIImageView {
    if let image = imageView.image {
        print("EXISTS!")
    }
}
```

This can be shortened to

```
if let imageView = self.view.viewWithTag(211) as? UIImageView,
    let image = imageView.image {
    print("EXISTS!")
}
```

or

```
if let image = (self.view.viewWithTag(211) as? UIImageView)?.image {
    print("EXISTS!")
}
```

Comment: This is the fastest answer I've ever got! Thanks a lot, I will try this out in a minute and write you back.

Comment: Cool, thank you, everything worked for me. The UIImageView exists, so the first thing also works for me.